# Having a button add text to a UITextField in swift

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I am creating a post to twitter app and want to add various text to the UITextField from buttons that can be selected. The UIButton are for various hashtags to speed the process of writing a tweet. I have tried a couple the solutions found on Stack but none seem to work and they are all in Objective-C.

Screenshot of compose tweet view before buttons touched.

http://postimg.org/image/5qoyk6673/

Screenshot of compose tweet view after button selected and text added to text field.

http://postimg.org/image/vp08wsa6b/fa7c7a83/

```
class TweetComposeViewControler: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
var selectedAccount : ACAccount!

@IBOutlet var tweetContent: UITextView!

@IBAction func specializedButton(sender: UIButton) {
    tweetContent.text = sender as UIButton
    tweetContent.text.stringByAppendingString(specializedButton(titleLabel.text))

}

func insertHashtag(sender: UIButton!) {
    tweetContent.text = tweetContent.text.stringByAppendingString(sender.titleLabel.text)
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend posting your current code.

Comment: `class TweetComposeViewControler: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    var selectedAccount : ACAccount!

    @IBOutlet var tweetContent: UITextView!
    
    @IBAction func specializedButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        tweetContent.text = specializedButton.titleLabel.text
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tweetContent.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        
    }`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the UITextFields text to the title of your UIButton:

```
txtField.text = hashTagButton.titleLabel.text
```

And if you want to append the text:

```
txtField.text = textField.text.stringByAppendingString(hashTagButton.titleLabel.text)
```

In order to have your buttons update the text upon pressing them you need to add a target selector for when the buttons are pressed. This can be done via Storyboard or programmatically.

**Programmatically**

You would add the same selector to all buttons using this:

```
 hashtagButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("insertHashtag:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

This will call the insertHashtag function whenever the `hashtagButton` is pressed. Because of the `:` at the end of the selector, it will also pass itself as a parameter so you can use it to get the button's title rather than creating a different selector for each button.

```
func insertHashtag(sender: UIButton!) {
   txtField.text = textField.text.stringByAppendingString(sender.titleLabel!.text)
}
```

**Using IBAction**

```
@IBAction func insertHashtag(sender: AnyObject) {
    txtField.text = sender as UIButton 
    textField.text.stringByAppendingString(btn.titleLabel!.text)
}
```

Here you cast the sender paramter as a UIButton since you know a UIButton is the type of the object which called it.

If you know that *only* UIButton's will cause this method you can do this:

```
@IBAction func insertHashtag(btn: UIButton ) {
    txtField.text = sender as UIButton 
    textField.text.stringByAppendingString(btn.titleLabel!.text)
}
```

**Response to your update**
The code you added needs to be fixed to look like this:

```
@IBAction func specializedButton(sender: UIButton) {
    tweetContent.text.stringByAppendingString(sender.titleLabel!.text)   
}
```

Here `sender` is your UIButton and you pass it as a UIButton so you do not need to convert it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74267/discussion-on-answer-by-chrissukhram-having-a-button-add-text-to-a-uitextfield-i).